# Centre tapped transformer outputting uneven voltages, have I damaged it?

Tags: transformer, toroidal, toroid

I am modifying a KEF PSW 2010 amplifier board to make it run cooler. The mod involves removing voltage dropper resistors on the input to the L7815 and L7915 regulators (+15V and -15V) and replacing them with an auxiliary circuit consisting of a transformer, bridge rectifier and capacitors. The circuit should create +24V and -24V to feed L7815 and L7915 regulators.

Currently i have approx 18.9V and -16.7V DC out of the auxilary circuit.

Have I damaged the transformer (during testing)?

Testing:

1. voltage was tested with a multimeter.
2. DC voltage is tested between AC0 and the +ve or -ve rail after capacitors C1 and C2.
3. AC voltage is tested at the input to the bridge rectifier (between AC3 and AC0 OR between AC4 and AC0).

FYI:
The main transformer is a toroidal one with 2x 115V primaries and 2x 37V secondaries. The secondaries are in a centre tapped configuration (+37V 0 -37V). One of the primaries has an additional live wire that connects to a fuse inside the transformer.

The auxiliary transformer is a 6VA transformer with 2x 115V primaries and 2x 15V secondaries. This the [transformer](https://uk.farnell.com/multicomp-pro/mcp-126-006-415/chassis-mount-transformer-6va/dp/4220567).

The circuit is:
[image: original circuit (with small changes]
[image: auxiliary circuit]

Comment: The words describing the circuit can be heavily misinterpreted so, draw a circuit of what you mean please.

Comment: We don't know what transformer you used and thus what it should output. We also don't know how you connected it and where to know what kind of load there is and how much it consumes. Nor you don't say how you measured the voltages and with what. Heavier load will cause more voltage drop.

Comment: It's unlikely you've damaged the transformer if it is outputting voltage and there is no evidence of damage such as scorched insulation odour or smoke. However there is a vast panoply of other things that could be wrong.

Comment: Unless something else is wrong, the 7915 will now be toast due to incorrect pinout. But if they were already in the orignal circuit, they might be just drawn wrong.

Comment: I would expect about +/-19V with 100mA load on each. Your 7915 is connected incorrectly in the schematic.

Comment: I have corrected the schematic. The pinout on the 7915 and 7815 was drawn incorrectly.

Comment: You have *changed* pin designations. Check with reputable sources for pinout.